# Tensorboard Error - NameError: name 'tensorboard' is not defined

Tags: tensorboard

I am now learning tensorflow but am unable to get tensorboard to work. I tried the simple program below with no luck. The program works before I use the tensorboard code but when I use the tensorboard code I get the following error:

```py
NameError: name 'tensorboard' is not defined
```

Please any assistance is apppreciated.

```py
import tensorflow as tf


a = tf.constant(5, name="input_a")
b = tf.constant(3, name="input_a")
c = tf.multiply(a,b, name="mul_c")
d = tf.add(a,b, name="add_d")
e = tf.add(c,d, name="add_e")

sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(e)
output = sess.run(e)

writer = tf.summary.FileWriter('/tmp/newtest', graph=sess.graph)

print(sess.run(e))

tensorboard --logdir /tmp/newtest
```

Comment: What gave you the idea you should insert `tensorboard --logdir /tmp/newtest` into your Python program? That's not Python; that's a shell command line.

Comment: user2357112,,,thank you so much for your reply...i really appreciate it...all the reading i have done didnt indicate it was a shell command..i am now learning and you really helped me out here..that worked!...very much appreciated!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is already 'answered', but, to give a sample of what I did, regarding this, and I hope it helps you or others.

This is just covering ending overhead of triggering & showing tensorboard.

```
import subprocess
import webbrowser
import time

logLocation = 'tflearn_logs'

print("\r\nWould you like to see the visual results (y/N)? ", end='', flush=True)
answer = input()
if answer.strip().lower() == "y":
    port = str(8018)
    print("Starting Tensorboard to visualize... ")
    process = subprocess.Popen(['tensorboard', "--logdir='" + logLocation + "'", '--port=' + port])

    # Wait for a few seconds, give the tensorboard a headstart
    time.sleep(5)

    print("Opening Tensorboard webpage... ")
    url = 'http://127.0.0.1:' + port + '/'
    # Path differs per OS (Windows, Linux, iOS)
    chrome_path = 'C:/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe %s'
    webbrowser.get(chrome_path).open(url) 

print("Press enter to quit... ", end='', flush=True)
answer = input()
if process is not None:
    process.kill()
```